# C# SmtpClient Send Failure: An invalid argument was supplied

Tags: c#

I am trying to send mail using Office365 mail server and have continuously run into this problem/exception with no resolution in sight. Have done numerous research on this and cannot find any post with similar issue:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(AddressFamily addressFamily, SocketType socketType, ProtocolType protocolType)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at whatever.Main()
```

Here is my C# code (I have simplified it for ease of analysis):

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

class whatever
{
    static int Main()
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(
                "blah@blah.com",
                "blah@blah.com",
                "no subject",
                "no body");

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("outlook.office365.com");

            client.Port = 587;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("blah@blah.com", "mypass");
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            client.Send(mail);
            Console.WriteLine("mail Send");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

A similar Sendmail method using Python with TLS (port 587) works but not this C# code so there should be no connection issues between my PC and Office365 SMTP server.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Not that this is your issue, but you should be calling `client.Dispose()` to close the SMTP connection correctly. Also try running Visual Studio with administrative privilages and try this again.

Comment: We tried this an it worked: 1. `telnet outlook.office365.com 587` 2. `ehlo`. The server response included `250-STARTTLS`, so the server does advertise that it supports TLS. We thought that might have been the problem, but apparently it is not. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Ron and Shaun: Unfortunately I do not have administrative privileges on my PC. Furthermore, I do not have Visual Studio installed on my PC so I'm actually using Windows 10 MS Framework 4.0's SmtpClient and whatever namespaces that are currently available in there. Frankly, I'm actually using csc.exe to compile my cs code ;-). I've actually tried client.Dispose() code and the error is still the same. Finally, on my Python code which does work (BTW, outlook.office365.com is the correct smtp and I've used smtp.office365.com with the same error), starttls() is called followed by login()

Comment: (continue) and finally sendmail(). On C#, there's only enablessl and I'm not sure whether login has been established or not even though Credentials have been defined. Frustrating to say the least.

Comment: @CSY In case you haven't solved this, we added a new answer that might shed some light on the SocketException.

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably specific to your machine, because your code works using our Office365 account on our machine. Maybe on your machine port 587 is already in use. We need more detail about that `SocketException`.

## Determine the details of that SocketException

Inspect the `InnerException` error code/message like this:

```
try {

    // perform the email sending routing

} catch (Exception ex) {

    var inner = ex.InnerException as System.Net.Sockets.SocketException;
    System.Console.WriteLine(inner.ErrorCode);
    System.Console.WriteLine(inner.Message);
}
```

The output will look like something like this, but (maybe) with a different error code and message.

```
10048
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) 
is normally permitted
```

If the error message does not provide enough information, match the error code with [the error codes list here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx). That should provide the details necessary to resolve the problem.

## More detail about those troubleshooting steps

This is the inner exception that you were/are receiving:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An invalid argument was supplied

It was/is happening on the call to this constructor:

```
System.Net.Sockets.Socket(
    AddressFamily addressFamily, 
    SocketType socketType, 
    ProtocolType protocolType)
```

The [documentation for that constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b86d684(v=vs.110).aspx#Exceptions) says:

> If this constructor throws a SocketException, use the SocketException.ErrorCode property to obtain the specific error code. After you have obtained this code, refer to the Windows Sockets version 2 API error code documentation in the MSDN library for a detailed description of the error.

That's what we showed how to do in the above steps.

May the force be with you.

Comment: Thanks Shaun. I've re-executed my code based on your exception code above and the error code returned was 10022. According to MSDN:  "WSAEINVAL10022 

Invalid argument.
Some invalid argument was supplied (for example, specifying an invalid level to the setsockopt function). In some instances, it also refers to the current state of the socket—for instance, calling accept on a socket that is not listening." I do believe the current state of the socket should be fine as executing from Python works perfectly. Is it possible if you can provide me with clues on setsockopt though? TIA.

Comment: @CSY I'm afraid I do not have any more info for you. If I were in your shoes, I would contact Microsoft support.

Comment: Great news: I was able to get it working **after** installing VS 2017 Community version. I guess I need VS after all...sigh. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Hmm. Good to know @CSY. I wonder what VS 2017 installed that made it work.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4), it seems your smtp address is incorrect.

Please change:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("outlook.office365.com");
```

To:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com");
```

More info [here](https://itservices.usc.edu/office365/emailclients/).

Comment: I've tried that already (smtp.office365.com) as well before posing this question to no avail (same error message).